What Post-Quantum Secure Hash Functions Are Available for Usage in Solidity Smart Contracts?
Question:
I am developing Solidity smart contracts and am concerned about the future security of cryptographic hash functions in the face of quantum computing advancements. Specifically, I am looking for hash functions that are considered post-quantum secure and can be implemented within the constraints of the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM).
Key Points:
Post-Quantum Security: The hash function should be secure against potential quantum computing attacks.
EVM Compatibility: It needs to be feasible to implement and use the hash function within the Solidity language and the EVM environment.
Performance Considerations: Given the gas cost limitations on the Ethereum network, the hash function should be reasonably efficient in terms of computation and gas usage.
Questions:
Are there any known post-quantum secure hash functions that have been implemented in Solidity?
What are the best practices for ensuring the longevity and security of hash functions in smart contracts in the face of future quantum computing developments?
If no direct post-quantum secure hash functions are currently available for Solidity, what are some recommended approaches or workarounds to enhance the security of existing hash functions?
Any insights, references, or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Post-quantum algorithms are already available. Integrating these algorithms into a smart contract or the blockchain itself involves different approaches:
Smart Contract Integration: You can create smart contracts that use post-quantum algorithms. However, this will likely increase the gas cost of transactions due to the complexity and size of the quantum-resistant algorithms.
Chain Upgrade: Proposing an upgrade to the blockchain to incorporate post-quantum algorithms is another approach. This would involve a hard fork and consensus among the community. It’s a challenging task but feasible with coordinated effort.
It's important to note that by the time we have quantum computers powerful enough to break current encryption patterns, it’s likely that new algorithms and standards to protect against such threats will have been developed.
Ultimately, transitioning to quantum-resistant cryptography will likely require forking the blockchain to adopt new cryptographic algorithms. While not easy, it is certainly possible.

for now which qunatum secure hash functions are used in smart contracts ?

are you aware of such hash functions ?
